# Square Root Matrix of a Diagonalizable Matrix is Diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I have a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ that is diagonalizable with two real, positive eigenvalues.  I am asked to find all square roots of A

A is diagonalizable.  Therefore, $A = SDS^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal and has entries as the two eigenvalues.  Therefore, there are obviously at least 4 square root matrices: $SD'S^{-1}$ where $D'$ has $\pm \sqrt{\text{eigenvalue}}$ at each entry.

But now I want to show that these are the only ones.  These are obviously the only diagonalizable square roots.  But how do I prove that there are no other square root matrices that are not themselves diagonalizable.

In other words, how do I prove that if A is as above then sqrt(A) must be diagonalizable?

Answer (score 2):

Prove the contrapositive. If $B$ is not diagonalizable, it is of the form $SJS^{-1}$, where $J$ is a size-2 [Jordan block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix). So if $B$ also has positive eigenvalues, $B^2=SJ^2S^{-1}$ will not be diagonalizable.

However, the rest of your proof isn't totally valid. In particular, the identity matrix satisfies all your conditions, but has a lot more than 4 diagonalizable square roots...

EDIT: If $A$ has distinct eigenvalues, then $\sqrt{A}$ does as well, which means it's guaranteed to be diagonalizable.

Comment: I should say that two real, positive, distinct eigenvalues

Comment: only if J is not nilpotent, I'd say..

Comment: However, I am not sure why if B is not diagonalizable it must be of the form you have stated (I am not sure what a Jordan block is).

Comment: Why is it that √A also must have two distinct eigenvalues?

Comment: @Micah  I apologize but I am still confused.

If √A has two distinct eigenvalues then A clearly does as well.

But I am not sure why the reverse implication holds.

That if A has two distinct eigenvalues, √A must as well. 

(I get intuitively why this must hold but not formally).

Comment: It's actually possible that $\sqrt{A}$ has two distinct eigenvalues (say, $\pm \lambda$), and $A$ only has one eigenvalue (in this case, $\lambda^2$). But if $\sqrt{A}$ has only one eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $A$ will have also have only one eigenvalue $\lambda^2$ (one way to see this is to consider determinants — if $\lambda$ is the only eigenvalue of $\sqrt{A}$, it must have determinant $\lambda^2$, so $A$ must have determinant $\lambda^4$ and also must have $\lambda^2$ as an eigenvalue, which means the other eigenvalue is also $\lambda^2$).

Answer (score 0):

Let the two eigenvalues of $A$ be $a,b>0$ and let $B$ be a square root of $A$.

If $a\ne b$, the polynomial $(x^2-a)(x^2-b)$ annihilates $B$; if $a=b$, the polynomial $x^2-a$ annihilates $B$. In either case, $B$ is annihilated by a polynomial with distinct real roots (because $a,b>0$). Hence the minimal polynomial of $B$ has distinct real roots and $B$ is diagonalisable over $\mathbb R$.